# How to test Kafka Consumer with testontainer and @KafkaListener in integration testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, testcontainers

I'm still new to using Kafka. Following is my code:

This is my consumer:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConsumer {

     private final KafkaMapper kafkaMapper;
     private final ExchangeRepository exchangeRepository;

     @KafkaListener(topics = "mock", groupId = "group", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public SomeEntity saveMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaDTO> record) {
KafkaDTO dto = record.value();
SomeEntity someEntity = kafkaMapper.toSomeEntity(dto)
return exchangeRepository.save(someEntity);
}
```

Configuration for test:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class SpringTestConfig {

     private String groupId = "group";

     @Bean
     public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaDTO> consumerFactory() {
         Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers); // we need to somehow put the container port here
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaDTODeserializer.class);
         return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
     }

     @Bean
     public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaDTO> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
         ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaDTO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
         factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
         return factory;
     }

}
```

The test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class KafkaConsumerIntegrationTest {
     private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "mock";
     private static KafkaProducer<String, KafkaDTO> producer;
     @Container
     private KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer();
     @Container
     private PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15");
     @Autowired
     private CurrencyDictRepository currencyDictRepository;
     @Autowired
     private CurrencyExchangeRepository currencyExchangeRepository;
     @Autowired
     private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;



     public static Stream<KafkaDTO> createDto() {
         KafkaDTO usd = new KafkaDTO(" ");
         return Stream.of(usd);
     }

     @BeforeEach
     public void createProducer() {
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
         properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
         properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
         properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
         producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
     }

     @ParameterizedTest
     @MethodSource("createDto")
     @KafkaListener(topics = "mock", groupId = "info", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
     void testSaveMessage(KafkaDTO dto) {
         ProducerRecord<String, KafkaDTO> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC_NAME, dto);
         producer.send(producerRecord);
         ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaDTO> record = new ConsumerRecord<>(TOPIC_NAME, 1, 1234, null, dto);

         SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity("message")

         SomeEntity someEntitySaved = kafkaConsumer.saveMessage(record); // I don't know how to run this method to read from Kafka, rather than manually passing the object.

         Assertions.assertEquals(someEntitySaved, someEntity);
     }
}
```

I want to test receiving a message from Kafka in a test container.
but there were 2 problems:

1. How do start receiving messages from Kafka in a test? In the code I use `@KafkaListener` over the method and a `ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaDTO> record` is sent to the method using spring, and then I process it.
   But how can I set this up in tests so that I receive this object from Kafka in the container?
2. How can I transfer the container port address to the configuration from a test container during startup?
   Is it possible to somehow add test container creation to the configuration class? There is a `getBootstrapServers` method to get the port.
   it needs to be called when setting the configuration in the configuration class.

but kafkaContainer is located and launched in another file, in the test class

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
```

How can you call the `getBootstrapServers` method in a test class on a `kafkaContainer` object and put the value in **SpringTestConfig**?

If there are other solutions, I'd be glad to hear. Thank you.